# Java. Swing. Changing of component's order in a container

Tags: java, swing, containers

I'm using java Swing. I've created JPanel and filled it with Components.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
for (JComponent c : components) {
   panel.add(c);
}
```

I need to change order of some components. For certainty, I need to swap two of the components with defined indexes(oldIndex and newIndex).
I know, I can obtain all of the components through panel.getComponents().

I've found only one way to do this.

```
Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
panel.removeAll();
components[oldIndex] = targetComponent;
components[newIndex] = transferComponent;
for (Component comp : components) {
    panel.add(comp);
}                
panel.validate();
```

But it seems to me, that components are being recreated, because they loose some handlers(listeners) they have before such manipulations. 
Can you advise another way to reorder components in a container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your question is that we don't know who **targetComponent** and **transferComponent** are, and you might created new components. You can try this:

```
Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
panel.removeAll();
Component temp = components[oldIndex];
components[oldIndex] = components[newIndex];
components[newIndex] = temp;
for (Component comp : components) {
    panel.add(comp);
}                
panel.validate();
```

Comment: Yes, u're right. Now works fine.
Thanks much.
Know it was rather stupid road-block =)

objects were gained like this:

JImageButton targetBtn = (JImageButton) container.getComponentAt(dtde.getLocation());
Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
JImageButton transferBtn = (JImageButton) tr.getTransferData(JImageButtonTransferable.DEFAULT_JIMAGEBUTTON_FLAVOR);

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the hierarchy events and others to fire, I think the only option is to customize the layout manager.

Comment: The trick is I want them. But they will be lost for the two components after reordering.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It allows component switching.

Comment: I can see only "choosing what to show" logic in CardLayout.
Have no idea how to use it in my case.

I've already had working component, but this reordering question wasn't still solved properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order to add every component:

```
panel.add(componentIndex0);
panel.add(componentIndex1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int oldIndex = -1;
// old list holder
ArrayList<Component> allComponents = new ArrayList<Component>();
int idx = 0;
for (Component comp : panel.getComponents()) {
  allComponents.add(comp);
  if (comp==com) {
    oldIndex = idx;
  }
  idx++;
}

panel.removeAll();

// this is a TRICK !
if (oldIndex>=0) {
  Component temp = allComponents.get(oldIndex);
  allComponents.remove(oldIndex);
  allComponents.add(newIndex, temp);
}

for (int i = 0; i < allComponents.size(); i++) 
  panel.add(allComponents.get(i));

panel.validate();
```

Comment: afaics, this doesn't solve the requirement (which was to _swap_ two components).